# Selecting a select option with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I am trying to use jQuery to set one of the options of a dropdown menu as the selected one. This is what I've tried: (The code is within a document ready block)

```
if($.cookie("regio"))
{
    $('#regio option[value="'+ $.cookie("regio") +'"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="regio">
<!-- Here are some options -->
</select>
```

Nothing happens after this. I have debugged all the values using firebug and the cookie does correspond to one of the select values. What could be the problem?

Comment: $.cookie("regio") contain some special chars??

Comment: Does `$.cookie("regio")` return a string value?

Comment: It doesn't contain special chars, and it's a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#regio').val($.cookie("regio"))
```

---

Example in a snippet:

```js
$("select").val("Second")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="First">First option</option>
  <option value="Second">Second option</option>
  <option value="Third">Third option</option>
  <option value="Forth">Forth option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @SimonH, it works. See the snippet. If in your case it doesn't, check that you are using the right string.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$.cookie("regio")` return a string value? If not, you will want to cast the returned value as a string before concatenating it. Otherwise, something like this:

```
var foo = 1 + "34";
```

is going to evaluate to "134" instead of the likely desired "35";